# serialize a java object with collection

Tags: java

i wanted to serialize an object with a collection of its own type ,serializing gives no issues but on deserializing the object doesent deserialize its collections ,i have the following object

```
package com.mars.distribution.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;`
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="Intermediary_freeFlow",schema="distribution")
public class IntermediaryFreeFlow  implements Cloneable,Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE )
    @Column(name="INTERM_ID")
    private int intermId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="INTERMEDIARY_FREEFLOW_RELATION",schema="distribution")
    private List<IntermediaryFreeFlow> intermediaryCollection=new ArrayList<IntermediaryFreeFlow>();


    public int getIntermId() {
        return intermId;
    }
    public void setIntermId(int intermId) {
        this.intermId = intermId;
    }
    public List<IntermediaryFreeFlow> getIntermediaryCollection() {
        return intermediaryCollection;
    }
    public void setIntermediaryCollection(
            List<IntermediaryFreeFlow> intermediaryCollection) {
        this.intermediaryCollection = intermediaryCollection;
    }
}
```

*

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing List with ArrayList in your code. Reason is ArrayList implements Serializable interface, where as List doesn't probably that could be the cause.

Comment: hi prashanth the problem has been solved , the root cause was the lazy fetching which i had used in hibernate changing that to eager solved my problem

Comment: the Collection object dont get initialized while using Lazy fetching as far as the list interface is concerned ur are right list dosent implement the Serializable interface but all their implement Classes do which dosent make any difference in serialization